# fix misspelled words in a corpus without dictionary

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, nltk, text-mining

We have a history of conversations between humans (any language, any vocabulary), so with a lof of spelling errors:

```
"hellobb do u hav skip?" => "hello baby, do you have skype?"
```

Before running a deep learning task against this data set (find synonyms etc..), I would like to fix these errors.

Is it a good idea? I've never worked with such bad quality data. Wondering if there is a "magic solution" to achieve this.

Else I plan to use:

- word embeddings (word2vec) to check if good and bad words are similar
- distance function between words
- if wordA is less famous wordB then fix(wordA) = wordB

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic solution at this moment to guaranty to fix all misspelling errors on your text but here are some possible options you can consider:

- **Dictionary-based approach**. I found [`Hunspell`](http://hunspell.github.io/) very handy in this case. It uses language modeling and Levenshtein distance to suggest the correct spelling. It is available on many natural & programming languages. Although it is a dictionary-based approach, it is superior to many sophisticated approaches. It is used in vast majority word-processing applications.
- **Statistical and traditional approach**. Another possible solution is to develop your own statistical models such as [language modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). Training language modeling on a large corpus, at character level & word level, can found many misspelling on the text. Many speech recognition and search engines use language modeling at their heart to fix the misspelling.
- **Deep learning approach**. If you look at [NLPProgress.com](http://nlpprogress.com), most of the [state-of-the-art research](http://nlpprogress.com/english/grammatical_error_correction.html) used seq2seq models to attack grammatical error problem. The main intuition behind these models is to train a neural network on pairs of sentences which network learns how to fix grammatical error. These approaches require quite a lot of pairs sentence to gives a reliable result. If the available corpora are not fit to your needs, you can generate your own misspelling e.g. by replacing some tokens in your text.

Comment: I tried hunspell, but it's not smart at all! (``h.suggest("helo") gives ['hole', 'help', 'helot', 'hello'``) whereas in my dataset I got lot of Hello. Maybe it miss a kind of rank function to override this behavior. I will give a look on other solutions you gave very interesting, as I am not a data scientist but more developer, a bit hard for me :/ thanks you.

Comment: Although it's not too smart, combining with some other technique gives promising results.